# Regex to split on capital letters and numbers that are acronyms

Tags: c#, regex, string

The following regex pattern splits strings on capital letters (eg. `GetDatabaseIDE` becomes `Get Database IDE`)

```
Regex.Matches("GetDatabaseIDE", @"([A-Z]+)([^A-Z])*").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

How could this regex pattern be changed to include numbers and that still facilitates for the current return pattern? (eg. `GetDatabase2FA` should return `Get Database 2FA`)

**EDIT:**

The desired regex pattern should split the strings like the following..

```
2FAGetDatabase ---> 2FA Get Database

Get2FADatabase ---> Get 2FA Database

GetDatabase2FA ---> Get Database 2FA
```

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
public static string ToSentence(this string text)
{
    string pattern;
    if (text.Any(char.IsDigit))
    {
        pattern = @"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])";
        return string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(text, pattern));
    }
    else
    {
        pattern = @"([A-Z]+)([^A-Z])*";
        return string.Join(" ", Regex.Matches(text, @"([A-Z]+)([^A-Z])*").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
var pattern = @"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])";
Regex.Split("2FAGetDatabase", pattern);
//2FA Get Database
Regex.Split("Get2FADatabase", pattern);
//Get 2FA Database
Regex.Split("GetDatabase2FA", pattern);
//Get Database 2FA
Regex.Split("GetIDEDatabase2FA", pattern);
//Get IDE Database 2FA
```